# REST naming best practice/opinions - is it OK to use just variables without any nouns?

Tags: rest, naming

Not sure if I'm using the terminology correctly here, but best explained on example:
Is it generally ok if I use for let's say API for retrieving population count in given area

```
/population/{state}/{city}/{district}
```

or I should be using

```
/population/states/{state}/citys/{city}/districts/{district}
```

**Case A** the API returns just one number, depending on how much you specify
**Case B** the API returns just one number, but you have to always specify every variable, meaning defining just state and city is invalid:

I suppose it is always better to opt for the more explanatory one. Or is there some other logic to it I might be missing?

Comment: There is no such thing as "REST naming conventions". REST doesn't have naming conventions.

Comment: Both are perfectly fine and the first looks a bit more elegant to me

Comment: I mind the fact that when you end up as a user in a postman switching between tabs like a madman and seeing bunch of urls, that end like /324/23/11 you get easily lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, with REST endpoints, the '/' indicates that you're accessing a sub-resource. So it really depends on what your trying to do.

From what I understood, your primary objective is to retrieve a population given a number of parameters.

So the `/population/state/{state}/city/{city}/district/{district}` convention will work, if you had something along the following in mind:

- `/population`: returns total population
- `/population/states/`: returns total population for each state
- `/population/states/{state_name}`: returns total population for
  given state and each of it's constituent cities.
- and so on

Note, I used plural for the sub-resource name, i.e. `states` rather than `state`.

If, however, you're only intending to return a single number rather than a breakdown, then an alternative to consider:

**GET** `/population?state=stateName&city=cityName&district=districtName`

Comment: I have updated the question, to further specify according your answer,  to make it more clean

Comment: I see. If you're always planning to return a single number, and never a sub-resource breakdown (i.e breakdown of population for all cities, etc.), I believe using parameters, rather than sub-resources, would be more relevant  (i.e. the GET example I provided). Firstly, because it reserves the usage of sub-resources for another time if and when required.

Comment: Secondly, if for instance, you want to add yet another level of filter in the future (somewhere between state and district), you wouldn't want to change the ordering and impact your consumers (i.e. instead of 'population/{states}/{city}, it becomes 'population/{states}/{newFilter}/{district}..'.  I don't think there's a right or wrong way of doing it, it's just a matter of attempting to reserve usage of sub-resources if not really required. If you're keen on sticking to only one of the options you provided, then your option 1 is better in my opinion.